# how to make string in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Expected OutPut**

**Model = GT-N8000, cordova_version = 3.6.4, OS = Android**

Hello 
I am trying to make one string as shown below But it is display the values not the name of values .I am not able to get **attribute  and =** in a striing
here is my code

```
var deviceInfo = ''

var deviceInfo = '';

deviceInfo += model = getModel() + ',';
deviceInfo += cordova_version = cordovaVersion() + ',';

deviceInfo += OS = getOS();

alert(deviceInfo);
function getModel() {
    return "GT-N8000"
}
function cordovaVersion() {
    return "3.6.4"
}
function getOS() {
    return "Android"
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nL7ouohv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
var deviceInfo = ''

var deviceInfo = '';

deviceInfo += 'Model = ' + getModel() + ',';
deviceInfo += 'cordova_version = ' + cordovaVersion() + ',';

deviceInfo += 'OS = ' + getOS() + ',';

alert(deviceInfo)

function getModel() {
    return "GT-N8000"
}

function cordovaVersion() {
    return "3.6.4"
}

function getOS() {
    return "Android"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u are using variables as part of your string:

> `var myVar = "string"; alert(myVar);` its the same of doing
>   `alert("string");`but doing `alert("myVar")` will alert your var
>   name as a string

so in your case:

```
deviceInfo = "MODEL = "+getModel()+", CORDOVA_VERSION = "+cordovaVersion()+", OS = "+getOS();
```

[the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61mo8u7a/)